# Two distinct given names that have the same pronunciation?

Tags: pronunciation, names, homophones

Are there any two distinct given names that have the same pronunciation? There are many such among, for example, Japanese-language and Chinese-language given names. I wonder if there are any in English/Western given names.

**P.S.**

But let's exclude cases where one is a shorthand or a "variant spelling" of, and hence somewhat closely related to the other. Examples:

- It seems John and Jon are not "distinct" if "Jon" is taken as an "alternate spellings" of "John" as indicated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon.
- It seems Brian and Bryan are not "distinct" as according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_(given_name) the two are "variant spellings" of, arguably, the same name.

**Summary**:

Examples of names that are homophones:

- Mark, Marc
- Neil, Niall†
- Gene, Jean
- Sherry, Cherie

† Neale is not included as it is a surname but I only want to include given names for this question.

Unideal answers as the two names arguably are alternate spellings of the same name:

- Brian, Bryan
- Ian, Iain
- Jon, John

Unideal answers as the two names are not typically homophones:

- Dawn, Don

Comment: What do you mean by 'distinct'? Spelled differently, have different meanings,....?

Comment: Spelt differently.

Comment: Leslie and Lesley; Jon and John; Lawrence and Laurence.

Comment: Brian and Bryan

Comment: Brian and Bryan are "variant spelling" according to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bryan_(given_name) and therefore, according to https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/416406/two-distinct-given-names-that-have-the-same-pronunciation/416407#comment994861_416407, is not the ideal case for this question.

Comment: Could you give me an example of one Chinese name and one Japanese name that fit what you're taking about?

Comment: As for English you want two distinct names, which you define as "spelt differently" but you don't want names that are  variant spellings of each other? I'm still not clear what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gene (short for Eugene, but also a name in it's own right) and Jean (Scottish version of Jane).

Comment: I believe that “Jean” can also be used  as a shortened form of “Regina”.

Answer (score 0):

Lots: Ian/Iain, John/Jon, Mark/Marc, ...

Comment: More to the point (because less obviously variants of the same name): Neil/Neale/Niall.

Comment: But let's exclude cases where one is a shorthand or a casual variant, and hence somewhat closely related to the other. It seems John and Jon are not "distinct" if "Jon" is taken as an "alternate spellings" of "John" as indicated in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jon.

Comment: 'Neale' is only a surname, I want given names only.

Comment: @Computist *Neal*, *Neil* and *Niall* are all commonly employed as forenames, and even *Neale* is not unknown as a forename.

Comment: Sherry (either from the Irish surname Ó Searraigh or short for Sherryl) and Cherie (originally from the French word *chérie* meaning *dear* or *darling*). So three etymologies, two spellings, and the same pronunciation in American English.

Comment: In some parts of the U.S. "Dawn" and "Don" are pronounced alike.